# How to pass complex linq result from the controller to view in C# MVC applciation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Developed MVC applciation and Code first approach, had three different class like

### First Class

```
 public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }    
        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }    
        ...       
        public virtual ICollection<UserDetails> UserDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

### Second Class

```
   public class UserDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserDetailsID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Users")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the first name")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAddress> UAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

### Three Class

```
   public class UserAddress
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserAddressID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserDetailsID")]
        public int UserDetailsID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual UserDetails UserDetail{ get; set; }
    }
```

Need linq result like:

```
var _result = (from users in objDBMVCSamp.User
               join details in objDBMVCSamp.UserDetail 
               on users.UserID equals details.UserID
               select new
               {
                  users.UserName,
                  users.Password,
                  details.FirstName,...
               }).ToList();
```

and also need another result like:

```
  var _result = (from users in objDBMVCSamp.User
                   join details in objDBMVCSamp.UserDetail 
                   on users.UserID equals details.UserID
                   join address in objDBMVCSamp.UserAddress
                   on address.UserDetailsID equals details.UserDetailsID
                   select new
                   {
                      users.UserName,
                      details.FirstName,...
                      details.UserID,
                      address.Address,...
                   }).ToList();
```

Need to show those result in in view. it's really possible or any other way to show without create a class.

### NOTE:

Above result are dynamic, so i though we not able to create a static class for those result. For this scenario what is best method to do this.

Comment: Create a view model that includes the properties you want to display then use `.... select new MyViewModel {...` and pass the view model to the view

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the value to view I'd rather suggest to create a ViewModel based upon what you want to show in view.

For example,

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public var MyValue1{get;set;}
   public var MyValue2{get;set;}
   public var MyValue3{get;set;}
   ...
   ...
}
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult MyControllerMethod(someType MyType)
{
   // setViewmodels value here
}
```

then in view

```
@model MyViewModel

<h1>Model.MyValue1</h1> @*this will display value of MyValue1*@
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Please check my question Now i update my question for the different  scenario, not for this much i want more different like this, In this case what i do.

Answer (score 1):

Define a view model that represents what you want to display

```
public class UserVM
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string EmailID{ get; set; }
  public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller

```
var _result = (from users in objDBMVCSamp.User
  join details in objDBMVCSamp.UserDetail 
  on users.UserID equals details.UserID
  select new UserVM
  {
    UserName = users.UserName,
    Password = users.Password,
    FirstName = details.FirstName,
    LastName = details.LastName,
    EmailID = details.EmailID,
    UserID = details.UserID
  }).ToList();
return View(_result)
```

View

```
@model List<UserVM>
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].UserName)
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Please check my question Now i update my question for the different  scenario, not for this much i want more different like this, In this case what i do.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you saying. Either add additional properties to you view model (`Address`,`City` etc) or create a new view view model for each scenario you want to handle

Answer (score 1):

These are the ways of passing data from controller to view

**1)** You can use the dynamic object ViewBag to pass data from Controllers to Views.

Add the following to your controller:

```
     ViewBag.MyList = myList;
```

Then you can acces it from your view:

```
     @ViewBag.MyList
   // e.g.@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList) { ... }
```

**2)** Using ajax service call

```
  $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Home/GetData",
        data: { function_param: values}
    });
```

3) Use strongly typed classes

```
   @model MyViewModel
  //e.g.@foreach (var item in MyViewModel) { ... }
```

For more information, kindly refer this link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/